# Related to permutations and combination, what is the name of this formula?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 3 options, each option has 2 possible value (binary). I'm trying to figure out how many possible variations there are...

[image: https://imgur.com/a/7MMh0Tw]

Is there a name for this formula?

I realize the formula itself is just 2^3, but I'm hoping to find the theory behind why it is.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)

Comment: Permutations with repetition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition